# Finding source code for native function in java

Tags: java

I've been looking at how [`java.io.Console`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/Console.java#Console.echo%28boolean%29) implements the `readPassword` function and I came across the native `echo` function. Being naturally curious I immediately set out to find the source code. I tried looking in `jdk/src/share/native` but to no avail. After further unsuccessful googling I turn to you.

Where can I find the source code for the native `echo` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/java/io/Console_md.c

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_java_io_Console_echo(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jboolean on)
{
    DWORD fdwMode;
    jboolean old;
    if (! GetConsoleMode(hStdIn, &fdwMode)) {
        JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "GetConsoleMode failed");
        return !on;
    }
    old = (fdwMode & ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT) != 0;
    if (on) {
        fdwMode |= ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;
    } else {
        fdwMode &= ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;
    }
    if (! SetConsoleMode(hStdIn, fdwMode)) {
        JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "SetConsoleMode failed");
    }
    return old;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the following from [this source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/java/io/Console_md.c):

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_java_io_Console_echo(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jboolean on)
{
    DWORD fdwMode;
    jboolean old;
    if (! GetConsoleMode(hStdIn, &fdwMode)) {
        JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "GetConsoleMode failed");
        return !on;
    }
    old = (fdwMode & ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT) != 0;
    if (on) {
        fdwMode |= ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;
    } else {
        fdwMode &= ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT;
    }
    if (! SetConsoleMode(hStdIn, fdwMode)) {
        JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "SetConsoleMode failed");
    }
    return old;
}
```